# Xrandr and nvidia-settings information inconsistent

Tags: nvidia, xorg, resolution, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have `primus`, `bumblebee`, `bumblebee-nvidia`, `nvidia-current`, `libdrm-nouveau1a`, `libdrm-noveau2`, and `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-lts-quantal` on my machine (should I delete the `noveau` stuff? It seems unnecessary since I have the current `nvidia` driver installed, but right now my monitor works and I don't want to break anything - I've had to clean install three times now).

The following seems inconsistent to me:

```
...$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
   1600x900       60.0*+   50.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

...$ less /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Section "Device"
    Identifier      "Default Device"
    Option  "NoLogo"        "True"
EndSection
```

And, consistent with my `xorg.conf` file (but not my actual display, as shown by `xrandr`), when I launch `nvidia-settings` with `optirun`, I see the following:

[image: xsettings]
I don't know what "No Scanout" means, but my screen's resolution is not `640x480`.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a similar set-up and would advise you not to delete the `noveau` drivers.

The reason being, when things go wrong and you need to rescue the system, the `noveau` drivers are the fail-safe drivers that you know will work.

*I believe I have the correct information here. I have recently changed laptops, and I can not remember exactly what was what!*

As you say, 640x480 is not really very useful and is obviously not really what is being displayed. Take a look at [this question and the answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55847/xrandr-not-listing-modes-in-xorg-conf?rq=1) with the green tick, it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks - I will make sure NOT to do anything with them. Can you answer the other part of my question?

Comment: It looks like the settings you have have got corrupted somehow. I am sorry, I can not remember where the settings were stored. but hopefully someone will be along shortly who can help. In the mean time I'll have a quick look around for you.

Comment: Did they really get corrupted? I **just** did a clean install and have had 1 hour of usage...

Comment: Just found a link which may help you. I have added it to my answer.

Comment: It could have been just a glitch. It's worth taking a look at the `xorg.conf` file just to make sure.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll take a look. I already did view the `xorg.conf` file - my question has the output of `less /etc/X11/xorg.conf` posted.

Comment: Sorry, getting carried away. I forgot to refer to the original question. :( that all looks good to me, but there again, I have not got much recent experience with the `xorg.conf` file.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9782/discussion-between-vf1-and-simplysimon)